# How to export es6 function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am creating an npm module with a load of self made functions that I can then import into my other projects. It was working until I did some refactoring and now cant work out why.

This is my shuffle func declaration and then exporting

```
const rhShuffle = function(array) {

}

module.exports = {
  rhShuffle
}
```

And this is me importing it and then exporting it again so it is available outside the project. this is my index.js file at route level. please not that when i declared the function straight in here and exported it, it worked fine

```
import rhShuffle from './src/shuffle';

module.exports = {
  rhShuffle
}
```

then in my other project I have imported it and console logged it and it says:

`_richsHelpers2.default.rhShuffle is not a function`

and when i console log:

`Object {rhShuffle: Object} "rh"`

it says its an object

Comment: `export default rhShuffle`

Comment: @OzgurGUL cheers. easy as that. why does that work?

Comment: Because you either import by name using curly braces or you export a default element.

Comment: @lilezek cheers

Comment: Don't mix commonjs with ES6 module syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** src/shuffle.js

```
const rhShuffle = function(array) {

}
module.exports = {
  rhShuffle,
}
```

Usage

```
var rhShuffle = require('./src/shuffle').rhShuffle;
```

**Option 2:** src/shuffle.js

```
const rhShuffle = function(array) {

}
export default rhShuffle
```

Usage

```
import rhShuffle from './src/shuffle';
```

Comment: Alternatively for Option1: `const {rhShuffle} = require(…);`

Comment: How can i export an async function and what if I want to export multiple async function, how can I do that using option 2?